# WPF: how to auto update ObservableCollection inside ListView

Tags: wpf

I have my object collection:

```
public class Data
{
   string name {get; set;}
   int progres {get; set;}
}

public ObservableCollection<Data> dataFiles { get; set; }
```

And my ListView:

```
    <ListView Name="lvDataFiles" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding dataList}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
                <Grid Margin="-6">
                    <ProgressBar Name="prog" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress}" 
                                 Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=ProgressCell}" 
                                 Height="16" Margin="0" Foreground="#FF5591E8" Background="#FF878889" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=prog, StringFormat={}{0}%}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="11" Foreground="White" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ProgressBarTemplate">
                <Label  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewHeaderStyle}">
                <GridViewColumn Width="425" Header="File name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}" />
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="ProgressCell"  Width="50" Header="Progress"
                                CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

My `ListView` has 2 columns: file name and Progress (that contain progress bar)
My Data collection has the Progress property that changing every few seconds.

Is it possible that my `ListView` `ProgressBar` will update automatic each time specific object (or several in the same time..) changing ? 
Or i need to go over my collection and update ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Data class must inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged, add a NotifyPropertyChange method and call that for each setter.

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _name;
   public string name
   {
      get { return _name; }
      set
      {
          _name= value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("name");
      }
   }
   private int _progress;
   public int progress 
   {
      get { return _progress; }
      set
      {
          _progress = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("progress");
      }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   virtual public void NotifyPropertyChange( string propertyName )
   {
       var handler = PropertyChanged;
       if (handler != null)
           handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

Comment: If you end up using this, note that the `INotifyPropertyChanged` is typically implemented in a base class that your viewmodel inherits from.  Don't try to implement it directly everywhere, you will just end up duplicating a ton of code.

Comment: This also will update all my collection if i get my object via different threads ?

Comment: It will; however, if the notification causes an update to the UI then you want to update the values on the UI thread. One thing you could do is use the UI dispatcher to invoke updates to the properties bound to UI elements (See System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke or System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke).